# Where to enter FIFA 13 Online Pass code

Tags: xbox-360, fifa-13

I recently purchased FIFA 13, and upon loading the game for the first time, it asked me to enter my online pass. I was too excited to waste my time with entering a code, I decided to leave it until later.

My problem is that I don't know where to go to enter the code now. Upon starting the game, it does not ask me to enter my online pass code. Most of the help on the internet is specific to the PS3.

I've tried to redeem codes on my xbox live account, my Origin account, and I've also tried to delete the game data on the xbox and reload the game - all to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try starting an online feature of the game, it should ask for you to redeem the code then.

Comment: It just says "Your profile does not have the permissions to access this feature". Unfortunately this is the case for most of the game modes on FIFA 13 :(

Answer (score 1):

Reedem Code through the Xbox Guide button is your best bet. If it says the code is invalid, you've either entered it incorrectly (try typing it slowly) or you'll need to get a new code as it's already been used and is duff.

Comment: The redeem code feature on XBOX Live needs a 25-digit code in the format: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX, whereas the FIFA Online Pass code is a 16-digit code in the format XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.

So no, that does not work. The text box changes the code's format to the 5-per-dash format

Comment: @NielSarvari Perhaps you should just go to play an online game. By default, it should prompt you for your code then.
Try clearing your FIFA cache or something. You've obviously got stored data whereby it assumes a code has 'been entered'...

Answer (score 0):

The code should be redeemed through the "Redeem Code" of the Xbox Dashboard, or through the [Xbox Live website](https://live.xbox.com/en-GB/RedeemToken?xr=shellnav).

Did you buy the game new? If you bought it pre-owned, and the code in the box isn't working, it's likely that the previous owner redeemed it.

Comment: I bought it new. The code on the Xbox live website asks for a 25 digit code, and it's for (I assume) xbox live game time only, so the code doesn't work there.

Comment: The website will work for any standard Xbox code... Not sure if FIFA uses it's own system. I'll try and check when I get home, though I expect someone else will answer by then. :)

Comment: The redeem code feature on XBOX Live needs a 25-digit code in the format: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX, whereas the FIFA Online Pass code is a 16-digit code in the format XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. So no, that does not work. The text box changes the code's format to the 5-per-dash forma

Answer (score 0):

A short search on the internet gives the [following advice](http://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121008104922AAJBPkj):

> Go to play an online mode and it should ask for the code to continue

I'm not sure if it works, because I entered my online pass while my first start of FIFA 13.

Comment: It just says "Your profile does not have the permissions to access this feature". Unfortunately this is the case for most of the game modes on FIFA 13 :(

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but: Do you have a Silver or a Gold account for your Xbox?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, and EA has posted a Support article about it:

https://help.ea.com/article/fifa-13-online-pass-workaround-for-ps3-or-xbox

> If you are encountering either no option to enter your Online Pass or the Online pass is giving you a corrupt message, follow the steps below:

For Xbox:

> 1. Go to http://live.com
> 2. Sign in with your Gamertag information (email and Xbox LIVE password)
> 3. Click on your Gamertag next to your Avatar picture on the top right.
> 4. Click Redeem Code.
>
> Once redeemed, you can also send it to your Download Queue. Login to your console, start FIFA 13 and you'll be prompted to Re-Enter/RE-Download your Online Pass.

For PS3:

> 1. Exit the game.
> 2. Go to the PlayStation store and click on View Downloads on the left-hand side.
> 3. In your downloads, you will see the Online Pass, as well as an option to re-download it. Simply re-download the Online Pass.